# Why can HAVING reference COUNT(column_name) but not the column_name itself?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to better understand how MySQL works. I came across a problem with subgroups. From question [Unknown column in 'having clause'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105812/unknown-column-in-having-clause), I understand why this code will return an error:

```
SELECT b.Title, b.Isbn
FROM Book AS b
INNER JOIN Writing AS w ON w.Book_id = b.ID
GROUP BY b.ID
HAVING w.Author_id = 1 AND b.Title LIKE "%Head%"
```

That error is: "Unknown column 'w.Author_id' in 'having clause'" because:

> The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as well.

But, if instead of `w.Author_id = 1`, I use `COUNT(w.Author_id) > 1`, the code exectues and works correctly:

```
SELECT b.Title, b.Isbn
FROM Book AS b
INNER JOIN Writing AS w ON w.Book_id = b.ID
GROUP BY b.ID
HAVING COUNT(w.Author_id) > 1 AND b.Title LIKE "%Head%"
```

So, my question is: what is it about `COUNT()` that makes `w.Author_id` accessible? I apologize if this is a silly/obvious question - I'm still a novice at SQL.

Comment: COUNT() doesn't make accessible, it makes logic behind in the syntax. w.Author_id=1 and count(w.Author_id)= 1 both conditions are totally different. If you want to add condition w.Author_id=1 then you can use in where clause. In Having a clause you should use a grouped field or aggregate function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation seems pretty clear on this subject.  But let me see if I can explain it better for you.

The `HAVING` clause is essentially a `WHERE` clause that "takes place" after the `GROUP BY`.  That is, the aggregation has already happened, so the data that is available is the *aggregated* data.

In your example, there is no `Author_Id` returned by the aggregation.  And MySQL doesn't know how to generate one.

However, `COUNT(w.Author_Id)` is an aggregated result.  MySQL can just add that (conceptually) to the results returned by the aggregation and filter on it.

Your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT Title, Isbn
FROM (SELECT b.Title, b.Isbn, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM Book b JOIN
           Writing w
           ON w.Book_id = b.ID
      GROUP BY b.ID
     ) b
WHERE cnt > 1 AND b.Title LIKE '%Head%';
```

That said, the query is better written as:

```
SELECT b.Title, b.Isbn
FROM Book b JOIN
     Writing w
     ON w.Book_id = b.ID
WHERE b.Title LIKE '%Head%'
GROUP BY b.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

You can filter on the `title` *before* aggregating and that is usually much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

When you put `w.Author_id` in the expression `COUNT(w.Author_id) > 1` you are satisfying the requirement for HAVING clause that

> *HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause **or columns used in aggregate functions***

while the ID column alone won't, because it is not part of the `GROUP BY` clause nor is within an aggregate function (which `COUNT` is).