# Why group by don't identify columns?

Tags: mysql, database

i write this query in Mysql Workbench :

```
SELECT sum(10*taux)
FROM carbone
GROUP BY elementID
HAVING count(*)>1 and type_line="poste" or count(*)=1
```

the error was : unknown column 'type_line' in 'having clasue'

even i have one table and i am sure that the table contains all the mention columns.

the problem appear also with the other columns

i try to use simple queries with type_line column and it works but the previous query didn't work until now even i change the name of column to test the others and its the same error
the second issue is that i want to display also id column however the query is not work

```
SELECT sum(10*taux),id
FROM carbone
GROUP BY elementID
HAVING count(*)>1 and type_line="poste" or count(*)=1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36105890/1427878

Comment: but i have also another type if i put it in where i will combine the two case, and the sum will be wrong

Comment: `HAVING SUM(type_line="poste") or count(*)=1`. COUNT(*) cannot be zero in HAVING, so `count(*)>1` is excess. `sum(10*taux)` is strange, `10*sum(taux)` is more reasonable.

Comment: thank you for the remarks, but the problem is until exist,

Comment: Your query is strange... Imagine that you have more than one `elementID`. You receive a lot of sums... how do you want to define what sum to what element belongs to?

Comment: *but the problem is until exist* You do something wrongly, it seems. https://dbfiddle.uk/zm5lxUJX

Comment: yes i have more than one elementid! becasue the id of element is the id of posts so becasue of that i specify that count must be more than 1 and the type must be poste to eliminate the element in this case however if there is no posts i must take the element so count equal to 1

Comment: Please post sample data and the expected result. Also, when you mix `AND` and `OR` in a condition, it's best to use parentheses so you don't get unexpected grouping.